# Access attributes on constructor with customized Control (C# - WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm facing a behavior I cannot explain...

I created a custom object (child of `System.Windows.Controls.Grid` for instance) in my C# application, and when I try to access the attribute value in the constructor such as `Name` or `Tag`, I have empty `string` and `null` object... 
Note that when I override the method `OnMouseEnter`, I have the values I want.
Note also that, in the constructor, if I set a timeout after which I call another function, the values of my attributes are not set either...

Here are some code samples:

The code of my custom object:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace myNamespace
{
    public class Test : Grid
    {
        public Test() : base() {
            string name = this.Name; // Name is equal to ""...
            if (this.Tag != null) // Tag is null...
            {
                string tag = this.Tag.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the code for the declaration of my custom object in the XAML:

```
<local:Test x:Name="myName" Tag="myTag"></local:Test>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Properties are set after construction, i.e. not before the constructor has finished. You may access the properties in an overridden OnInitialized method, or in a Loaded event handler.

Comment: @Clemens and the answer below by mm8 are right. If you really wanted to set them in the constructor for whatever reason, move the XAML code where you set the properties to the C# constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a property before you have created an instance of the class.

The XAML processor creates an instance of your class, the constructor is invoked and returns, and then then the `Name` and `Tag` properties are set. They are not set by the time the constructor excecutes.